# My code is working from the script editor but not as an add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, chrome-web-store, google-apps-script-addon

i have made a guessing on games with friends spreadsheet and i want to hide the code i wrote from the editors

I was reading a lot on the net about that and i seems that the best option is to make my code as an add-on, so i tried that and done everything [that guide said](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish) , the add-on added to my spreadsheet but the code is not working, not the onEdit and not the Trigger (that set up to work every hour). at the chrome web store i think i did everything fine (again i used the guide) as ["draft"](https://image.ibb.co/mWJ6eJ/1.jpg) status  or ["Published to Testers"](https://image.ibb.co/eJRsKJ/2.jpg) not difference [its not working!](https://image.ibb.co/jDB3Ry/3.jpg)  trying hours to make it work but i couldn't,  im new to codding and that project went bigger then i expected, i must hide that code ill appreciate any help!

this is my code:

```
var colMin = 7; 
var minRow = 3;

function onEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var currRow = range.getRow();
  var currCol = range.getColumn();

  if(sheet.getName() == "Bets") {
    if(currCol >= colMin && currCol <= getLastCol("Bets") && currRow >= minRow) {
      betingRange(sheet, ss, currRow, currCol);
    } else if (currCol == 5 && currRow >= minRow) {
      dataValBuilder(currRow, sheet.getRange(currRow, 5).getValue());
    }
  }

  if(sheet.getName() == "Players") {
    if(currCol == 3) {

.............................. etc...................

..............using some Protection and named ranged commands........

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().setNamedRange(player.gamesLogNR, gamesLogSheet.getRange(3,lastColgamesLog+3,1000));

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addEditor(player.email);

  var protection = rangePro.protect().setDescription(player.name+" betting area, player id: "+player.id);
  protection.setRangeName(player.betsNR);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (player.email.length > 5) {
    protection.addEditor(player.email);
  }
}
 .......... etc...........

 .......timesup is the Trigger function (works hourly)............

function timesUp() {
  var betsScore = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("betsScoreHolder");
  var listsSheet = .......ETC........


        } else {
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().setNamedRange("rowsBlock", betsSheet.getRange(3, 7, (n+1)-3, betsLastCol-6));
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Again, the add on with my code already installed to the spreadsheet, but its not acting like the code in on the script editor,i mean its not working at all.

please help.

Comment: "it's not working" is not a valid problem description.  You mention the ***simple* trigger** function `onEdit`, yet your code uses features that require authorization, which **do not** work in simple triggers. Have you consulted your projects error transcripts?

Comment: @tehhowch thanks for the comment, sry about the title its the best i had >.> ill change the edit to  install-able trigger hope it will work, and about the error i dont really know how i need to do it, can you pint for me please? of show me example, thanks again!

Comment: @EliGueta See [Troubleshooting | Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting)

Comment: @tehhowch - Your comment was on point. i manage to use installable triggers and the add-on is working great! Thanks.